# align-items with justify content not working properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make the 2 `li` in the last row, next to each other, and not in the middle. I am using flex, so that it can be responsive in smaller screens.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VexZQK

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 800px;
  list-style: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  display: flex-item;
  padding: 15px 0;
  transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1);
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Your li is dynamic ?

Comment: not sure it is a duplicate, if desire output is : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PZeYdE then  it doesn't require flex. If it does, a pseudo-element :after will do

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:\

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 800px;
  list-style: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display:inline-block;
}

li {
  display: flex-item;
  padding: 15px 0;
  transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1);
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/ftno1q4a/)

Comment: Why? downvote Sir Can u Explain?

Comment: no idea, looks fine to me unless it is not output desired. to me flex is not even needed

Comment: okay thanks sir @GCyrillus